# How to get all last order status in magento?

Tags: php, magento, status, orders

How to get the last order status in Magento?

e.g an order might have multi status but I would like to get the last status order's status.
1.Pending=>2.processing=>3.**complete**

```
$myOrder=Mage::getModel('sales/order'); 
$orders=Mage::getModel('sales/mysql4_order_collection');
$orders->addFieldToFilter('status',array('in'=> array('processing', 'processed', 'pending fullfilment'))); 



$orders->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array("in" => array('8', '9'))); 

$orders->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'asc');

$allIds=$orders->getAllIds();

print_r($allIds).'</br></br>';

foreach($allIds as $thisId) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The two most obvious fields to order your collection by would be `entity_id` or c`reated_at`.  In almost all cases though, you should see identical results from each…

**By entity_id**

```
$status = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('entity_id', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    ->getFirstItem()
    ->getData('status')
;
```

**By created_at**

```
$status = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('created_at', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    ->getFirstItem()
    ->getData('status')
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I don't have 15 reputation to rate you . but entity_id is not the order_id, we still get the same result for that

Comment: entity_id is the id given to the order when its recorded in the database.  That's not the same as the increment id.  I would not recommend that you use the increment id to order your collection as this will not always run in sequence.  Use entity_id or created_at as shown in the example

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple actually:

```
$status = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('entity_id', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    ->getFirstItem()
    ->getStatus();
```

Note that `status` and `state` are two slightly different fields, you may want to double check and be sure that you're pulling the right one for your needs.

Comment: Didn't work for me,I think we have to use increment_id instead of order_id, is that what you meant?

Comment: This code is wrong and did not work for me so i downvoted.  ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', 'DESC') would this not actually need to be some sort of order ?  Also i cant see a field with the identifier of order_id.  It is causing an exception for me.  What version of magento did you test this on? If this is my mistake i happily upvote

Comment: Sorry about that, I wrote this without testing it.  I think the proper field name is `entity_id` as Drew mentioned in his answer.

Comment: thank you for confirming because i was unsure if i was unclear on something

Comment: But the way i understand how a collection work is that your code still is not good.  ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', 'DESC') is not good here